# Create session timeout modal based on user activity. If user stays active, don't show modal, but continue to refresh session

Tags: javascript, vue.js, session, timeout, setinterval

Need to launch a modal if user is idle for 10 minutes.  Once the modal is open the user will have 5 minutes to interact with the button inside the modal. If the button is clicked a request would be sent out to refresh the session.  If not, the user is logged out.

If the user stays active (keypress, mousemove, mousedown...etc), the modal should never show.

**PROBLEM:**

The session will still expire after 15 minutes if not refreshed. If the modal doesn't show the user will not have the opportunity to click the button and refresh the session.

However, I don't want to make the refresh request on every keypress/mousemove.  How would this timer be setup to make the refresh request intermittently to cut down on API requests?

Using Vue.js and Vuex.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making a function (say, checkActivity) that runs a setInterval that will add event listeners to the page every, say 6 minutes. Inside that function, you could add:

1. A setTimeout that will display the modal after 3.5 minutes,
2. a setTimeout that will log them out after ~4 minutes,
3. In the event listener(s), you could have them run a function that removes all of the listeners after the event is fired, clear the above two setTimeouts (using clearTimeout) and run the checkActivity function (to check again after 6 minutes).

Also, after writing this answer I found a couple of good resources that may help: 
https://css-tricks.com/detecting-inactive-users/
which even has a Vue implementation, or https://thisinterestsme.com/javascript-detect-user-activity/